# How to load contents into a unique div when multiple divs with same class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am having an HTML layout like follows.

```
            <div class="container">
                // Some contents are here in this level
                <div class="sub-container">
                    // Some contents are here in this level
                    <div class="sub-sub-container">     
                    // Some contents are here in this level
                    ......
                        .....
                            .....
                            .....
                        .....
                    ......
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>


        <div class="dynamically_added"> 
            <div class="container">
                // Some contents are here in this level
                <div class="sub-container">
                    // Some contents are here in this level
                    <div class="sub-sub-container">     
                    // Some contents are here in this level
                    ......
                        .....
                            .....
                            .....
                        .....
                    ......
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that, when I am trying to update the sub-container or sub-sub-container (simply any div nested deep inside the main (original) container div) div it is updating the contents of the dynamically added container also. How can I prevent it, so that only the original contents are updated?

Comment: What code do you use to load with?

Comment: Well, that depends on your JavaScript code. You need to familiarize yourself with [jQuery's traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to target just the container you need. If you're responding to a click or some other event, use `this` to target just that DOM element. Otherwise, start at the `body` element.

Comment: @Krycke: simple ajax request.

Comment: Sorry I mean how are you knowing what and where to add the data, is it as @Blazemonger said with a `click` event on a `div`, or do you just want to access a specific `div` with a class of `sub-container` that doesn't have a parent `dynamically_added`?

Comment: @Krycke : Yes that exactly is what I need. The contents should not be added to dynamical container. It should only replace the corresponding div inside the original container.

Comment: If the first container is not dynamically added I would suggest to simply add an extra class for easy access.

Comment: @Krycke : I can add that. If I add that, will the code be more simple? I am not using the method by João Silva explaied below.

Comment: @Mic I added an extra answer for you below.

Comment: @Krycke : thanks for that. I will try that. Will it work in deep nested divs also?

Comment: @Mic Should do, no problem. Although if you have nested divs with the same classes, the selection will find all of them, and you will be able to add more unique classes on the way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to exclude `div`s that are inside `.dynamically_added`:

```
var $div = $(".sub-sub-container").filter(function () {
   return $(this).closest(".dynamically_added").length == 0;
});
```

Thus, in your example, this will *filter* out every `div` that matches the selector that are within the `div` with the class `.dynamically_added`, and include all others.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XgHWe/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `:eq()` selector

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".sub-container:eq(0)").html("content for first div"); // for first div
    jQuery(".sub-container:eq(1)").html("content for second div"); // for second div
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var container = $('div[class!="dynamically_added"] > .container');
```

should give you every element with a class `container` that is not directly nested under a `div` with the class of `dynamically_added`

Comment: This won't fetch the sub-containers though, such as `sub-sub-container` or `sub-container`.

Comment: True, but that would be easy to access from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the extra class `"static"` to the static container up top:

```
<div class="static container">
    // Some contents are here in this level
    <div class="sub-container">
        // Some contents are here in this level
        <div class="sub-sub-container">     
            // Some contents are here in this level
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

you can just do:

```
$sub_container = $('.static .sub-container');
```